# Distributions of eigenvalues for matrix normal distribution: related references

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, eigenvalues, perturbation-theory

I am interested in the distribution of the eigenvalues of matrices that are sampled from the [matrix normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution).

I am sampling from $p(X \mid M,U,V)$ and let's assume that I know the eigenstructure of $M$.
The way I sample from the distribution is $M + \sqrt{U}*randn(d,d)*\sqrt{V}$, where $randn(d,d)$ is the MATLAB notation for a $d \times d$ matrix with each element being i.i.d. $N(0,1)$.

When I check the eigenvalues of the samples, I get the following:
[image]

The red dots correspond to the eigenvalues of the samples and the big green dots correspond to the eigenvalues of the mean matrix $M$.

It looks like there may be some related theory for this problem since each eigencluster looks like proper 2-d Gaussians. If you can point to the related references/theory that would be really nice. As a side note, I am an electrical engineer, so it would be better for me if the references are more accessible (i.e. less rigorous).

Thanks a lot in advance.

**edit:** For the figure below, M, U and V are as follows.
[image]

Comment: what are U and V? and what is M in the figure?

Comment: @oferzeitouni , If you can check the wikipedia link for the matrix normal distribution, M is the mean matrix, U is the covariance amongst the rows and V is the covariance amongst the columns.

Comment: What are U and V in the plot you give? the identity matrix?

Comment: @oferzeitouni, please see the edit. U is a scaled identity matrix, V is arbitrary.

Comment: Though, I should note that U does not need to be structured for my problem. For this specific figure, U was $0.5I_{6 \times 6}$.

Comment: So you are dealing with square matrices. This slightly simplifies matters. Not worrying about issues of regularity, the answer should be the given by the Brown measure of your matrix, which can be computed. See the [paper ](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9912242.pdf) for details, and [arxiv.org/pdf/0909.2214v2.pdf] and [arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5100.pdf] for examples where the  convergence is proved.

Comment: @oferzeitouni, thanks a lot for the references.